# Serve file via Slack slash command

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I would like to return a (downloadable) csv file when an user type a slash command, but I could not find a straight forward way to do it.

One option I've test is using a webhook and the Slack API, the slash command POST triggers a [file.upload](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload) via the Slack API, but in my opinion it's too much to the slash command logic. It needs additional app set up (webhook) and also the file is not sent as an answer to the slash command, but it's sent as a "regular message" by the bot in the channel and it's seen by everyone.

Another option was to return a link button from the slash command, redirecting to an endpoint that can serve a csv file. The issue is that when I click the button it opens a browser and then I can download the file, but outside from Slack.

Is it possible to avoid this redirection and keep everything happening within Slack ? I know it's really easy to prevent the redirection with javascript, but I don't know it's possible to add javascript to the slack button.

Otherwise, is it possible to return the file directly after the slash command without using a button ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `thread_ts` parameter in your call to `files.upload` so the file is uploaded as a threaded response instead of a separate message in the channel? You'll probably still need to user a webhook or chat.postMessage first in order to send the initial slash command response so that you have a valid `ts` to use. Otherwise you could also send the file directly to the user after the slash command is triggered by changing the value of the `channel` parameter in `files.upload`.